# Set up Traefik with Global Static IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, traefik

Traefik work with a LoadBalancer, so on Google Cloud Platform, it set up a static region ip.
It is my understanding that this ip will not be accessible everywhere. How can I make it work with a static global ip ?

Note: I'm using traefik with helm charts. https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/traefik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Global static external IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#reservedaddress) are available only to global forwarding rules, used for global load balancing. You cannot assign a global IP address to a regional or zonal resource.

A Cloud Compute Engine instance is a [zonal resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/global-regional-zonal-resources#zoneresource) [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/global-regional-zonal-resources#zoneresource) therefore it can't be assigned a global IP as you have correctly understood.

The Load Balancer is the one that will have the Global IP, and you will have access to the instance and services where you have the Traefik through it.

Comment: So, if I understood well, I need to set up a Global Load Balancer that will forward to the Region Load Balancer of Traefik ?

Comment: Hey, sorry I think I misunderstood your question. A [regional IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/global-regional-zonal-resources#regionalresources) in Cloud Platform refers to a resource that can be 'used' only  by instances that are in the same region as the address. For example if you have a static external IP reserved in asia-southeast1 region, you can assign it only to instances in that region, but the IP will be reachable globally.